# Put Pull to Refresh Control under TableView Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have attached headerView to UITableView. And I also want to use pull to refresh with tableview. 
I have attached headerview to tableview with this code:

```
tblView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

and used redresh controll as:

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!
refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

let tableController = UITableViewController()
self.addChildViewController(tableController)
tableController.tableView = self.tblView
tableController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl
```

Now issue is when I pull down tableview refreshcontrol showing but my header view position also changing with bounce effect. I don't want to change header position when I pulled down  I want to display refreshcontrol under header view.
my header view and refreshcontrol is shown in screenshots. I want header view's position static joined with navigation bar but when user scroll up headerview will also have to scroll.

[image: When pulled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1)adding header view inside uiviewcontroller not to headerview for tableview,

2)you can change the headerframe accord scrollView of the tableView contentoffset,It is a little complex

3) [github.com/CoderJackyHuang/StickyUpDownDemo](http://github.com/CoderJackyHuang/StickyUpDownDemo) this demo you can learn to solve your problem